# Mongoengine DeprecationWarning: insert is deprecated

Tags: python, insert, pymongo, mongoengine

I use mongoengine for mongodb operations in my project. I didn't got a warning like this before.

```
DeprecationWarning: insert is deprecated. Use insert_one or insert_many instead
```

I get the warning because of the line like below

```
 class Human(Document):
     name = StringField()

 Human.objects.insert([
      Human(name='Steve'),
      Human(name='Jack'),
      Human(name='Chris')
 ])
```

As i understand it **Human.objects.insert() is deprecated in new version**
but i cant find insert_many() instead of it. My program is still working but i can't resolve this error.
Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 1):

`insert_many` was introduced in mongoengine version 0.15.3. You can try to update your mongoengine.
If you don't want to do that try to :

```
collection = Human._get_collection()
collection.insert_many([{"name":"John"}, {"name":"Cookie Monster"}])
```

Comment: I updated mongoengine but it couldn't solve the problem, I know insert_many with {} but I need to use it like  **insert_many([Human(name='John'), Human(name='Cookie Monster')])**  , tried it and didn't work, insert_many should used like your example.So i think i should find different method

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert multiple documents into the collection you can use `insert_many` option (If you want to insert names of the people into different documents)

```
try {
       db.Human.insertMany( [
             { name: "John"},
             { item: "Jack"},
             { item: "Chris"}
       ] );
     } catch (e) {
       print (e);
     }
```